# How to find the number of times that 2 follows 3 in a list

Tags: python, list, while-loop

If I have a number 13245. What I need is to return how many times 2 follows behind number 3.

```
def thirtyTwos(n):
  lst=(map(int,str(n)))
  count=0
  i=0
  j=1
  while i<len(lst):
    while j<len(lst):
        if lst[i]==3>lst[j]==2:

                count+=1
        j+=1
    j=i+1
    i+=1
return count
```

But it turns wrong on some numbers. What should I do now?

Comment: what do you think  `if lst[i]==3>lst[j]==2:`  does? if one is True and one is False or both are True or one is False the other True?

Comment: you should rather check `if lst[i]==3 and lst[j]==2 and i+1 == j`  if `2` has to be directly after `3`

Comment: Why not just `str(n).count('32')`?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

```
def count_32(number):
    number = str(number)

    prev_char = ""
    count = 0
    for char in number:
        if char == "2" and prev_char == "3":
            count += 1
        prev_char = char

    return count

for x in [13245, 2345, 32432, 3323232]:
    print(x, count_32(x))
```

Output:

```
13245 1
2345 0
32432 2
3323232 3
```

Comment: one more question, can we use recursion to solve this problem? It seems to be more easy!

Comment: We can, but I doubt it is easier and certainly it is less efficient.

Comment: You could, I guess... Although I don't think it would be easier nor more efficient... Give it a try :)

Comment: @Błotosmętek, Sorry your comment didn't load until after I'd posted...

Answer (score 1):

An approach using regex:

```
import re                                                               

def count_32(number): 
    if not isinstance(number, str): 
        number = str(number) 
    return len(re.findall('32', number))
```